# Get full path and file name separately

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listbox

I'm trying to get the file name and full path of each file, the snippet below searches all folders in "foo" folder and outputs the file names in `ListBox`.

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\\foo")
Dim diar As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
Dim dra As FileInfo

For Each dra In diar
  ListBox.Items.Add(dra)
  ListBox1.Items.Add(would be full path here)
Next
```

But I also want to output the full path of each file in `ListBox1`, How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(dra.FullName)
```

Also, you could use `dra.Name` for the file name.

Comment: I hate it when the answer is so simple lol thank you Pietu, will mark as answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `linq` version if you will :)

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\\foo")
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(
    di.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) _
    .OfType(Of FileInfo).Select(Function(f) f.FullName).ToArray())
```